# Cannot find id property in React state using props

Tags: reactjs, constructor, react-props, super

While taking an online course on React and Spring Boot, I hit a roadblock in the constructor. I have seen someone ask the same question for this tutorial, but there wasn't a resolution.

Here is the code at present:

```
class TodoComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.id,
      description: "",
      targetDate: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }
```

From what I can determine, this problem is with `id: this.props.id`. When consoling the id by itself, it comes back as undefined. `description` and `targetDate` work as expected. When viewing the console while running the app, it says:

```
2:1 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

This I believe is because I am trying to call the id elsewhere, such as here:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let username = AuthenticationService.getLoggedInUserName()
    TodoDataService.retrieveTodo(username, this.state.id).then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        description: response.data.description,
        targetDate: moment(response.data.targetDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      })
    })
  }
```

The tutorial was made with an older version of React. The instructor did provide this update for React 6:

```
class TodoComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.params.id, // REACT-6 update
            //id: this.props.match.params.id, // Previous version
```

Yet when I try it, the app simply crashes. His other updated code prior to this has worked just fine.

Nothing I've tried has solved the issue, even though it seems like it should be pretty straightforward. If anyone has insight into this I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you use `TodoComponent`?

Comment: I've got basically 0 experience with class components, but if I were to try to debug this, I'd log `this.props` itself to see if there is an `id` prop anywhere to be found. Can at least make sure that it exists, an possibly helps you locate it on a child object if there is one.

Comment: I assume this uses React router? Is this component loaded directly from react router?

Comment: Also side point but your tutorial is out of date -- this is the older react API. I also question how good it is because copying the ID from props to state is a classic beginners error.

Comment: The tutorial is for a todo app and TodoComponent is what allows the user to get, create, update, and delete the todos.

Console logging this.props returns an empty object.

The app uses react-dom and react-router-dom, but this component only imports React and Component.

Yes that is clear. But the tutorial is a requirement and the instructor does provide updated code when applicable. This is the first time so far that the updates haven't worked.

Comment: Gotch. So this component is consumed elsewhere and passed to a `<Route>`? If so, can we see that also?

Comment: Is this what you mean?

            <Route
              path="/todos/:id"
              element={
                <AuthenticatedRoute>
                  <TodoComponent />
                </AuthenticatedRoute>
              }
            />

Comment: Almost forgot to mention that this is a todo list component that gets all the todos from the backend and lists them out on a page. It is able to do that just fine and the delete functionality works as well. It's when I try to add a todo or update one that this error occurs.